# Vuex, Vuejs if statement is true, do nothing

Tags: vue.js, vuex

so I have an ADD_TO_CART mutation in my Vuex.
However I want user to be able to add each item only once to Cart.
So I understand that I need to do if statement to check if the product is already in the Cart, however I do not know the syntax and how to write it really.

Here is my Vuex:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cart: [],
  },
  getters: {
    countOfCartProducts: state => {
      return state.cart.length
    },
    myCart: state => {
      return state.cart
    },
    getTotal: state => {
      return state.cart.reduce((total, lineItem) => Number(total) + Number(lineItem.price), 0);
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_TO_CART: (state, product) => {
      if () {

      }
      else {
        state.cart.push(product)
      }
    },
    REMOVE_FROM_CART: (state, product) => {
      state.cart.splice(product, 1)
    }
  },
  actions: {

  },
  modules: {
  }
});
```

Comment: _if statement is true, do nothing..._  Or even "if statement is false do something" ;)

Comment: yeah, tho what do i write to the if statement XD im not sure how to compare the id of items in there.

Comment: look for the documentation of Array.find() method

Comment: can you do this `if (state.cart.findIndex(item => item.id === product.id) !== -1)`, let me know if that helps

Comment: ADD_TO_CART: (state, product) => {
      if (state.cart.findIndex(item => item.id === product.id) !== -1) {
        return
      }
      else {
        state.cart.push(product)
      }
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ADD_TO_CART: (state, product) => {
      if (state.cart.findIndex(item => item.id === product.id) !== -1) {
        return
      }
      else {
        state.cart.push(product)
      }
    },
```

THIS IS WORKING NOW, THANKS EVERYONE!